# Is the sum of residuals in the weighted least squares equal to zero?

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares, regression-analysis

So I know that in OLS, the sum of the residuals is equal to zero. This makes sense. I also know that given any slope parameter its possible to rescale the intercept to where the sum of the u will be equal to zero. This makes sense. But in weighted least squares we give a different weight to each observation based on the variance structure, so would this still be true?

Heres my general attempt to think about this: If we weight an observation less and its far from the regression line, this seems like it would make the sum not equal to zero. Could it be that the sum of residuals AFTER the weights are applied sums to zero? This would make more sense to me. The problem is that the Assumption that E[u|x]=0 still holds in WLS. How does all this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In weighted linear regression models with a constant term, the weighted sum of the residuals is $0$.

Suppose your regression model seeks to minimize an expression of the form $$\sum_i \omega_i(y_i-Ax_i -B)^2$$

Here the $\{\omega_i\}$ are your weights.  Set the partial in $B$ to $0$ and suppose that $A^*$ and $B^*$ are the minimum.  Then we have: $$-2\sum_i \omega_i(y_i-A^*x_i-B^*)=0$$  Dividing through by $-2$ we see that the weighted sum of the residuals is $0$, as desired.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This is crystal clear. My only question, why do we then still keep the assumption from OLS that E[u|x]=0? Shouldn't it be that E[wu|x]=0? Where w is the weights. The expected values are just sums divided by the sample size, so if the sum of u's is not zero then how is the expected value? Thanks again

Comment: Can you cite a reference making this claim?  If I have three data points and weight the first and third by $1,000,000$ then I'll get the line connecting them (just a hair off).  So then the unweighted residuals will be (effectively) $0$ for the first and third, but clearly non-zero for the odd man out.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm in agreement. The source that confused me was this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares It refers to generalized last squares, but since weighted least squares is just a special case, I thought it would also hold. Look at the beginning of the method outline section. Now i realize they are referring to the error term not the residuals, maybe this is the difference?

Comment: Be careful:  My weighted least squares model has a constant term.  That's critical to the argument (I compute the partial in the constant term).  It is quite different in models without a constant term.  I am editing my post to reflect this.

Comment: Okay, so when there is a constant term, the sum of residuals may not be zero, but the weighted sum will be. When there is not a constant, the sum of residuals will be zero but perhaps not the weighted sum?

Comment: We might not be on the same page here.  I thought you were asking for properties of the best fitting line given that you want to fir some data more precisely than others.  Is that what you are looking at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28841/discussion-between-lulu-and-user243037).